# Prolem installing phonegap on windows 8 - unmet dependency

Tags: node.js, cordova

I follow [this official guide](http://phonegap.com/install/). It started with

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

It was running fine until the end, I got this **warning**:

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\phonegap -> C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js

npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phone
gap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client requi
res semver@'^2.2.1' but will load

npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phone
gap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver,

npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.2.1
```

I tried to run the `phonegap create my-app` command and got this error

```
'phonegap' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I thought it's not installed successfully, but I can see phonegap when I run `npm -g list`

Any solution? Thanks

Comment: I have solved this by re-installing NodeJS. A restart also needed after installing Phonegap to make the command line works.

I know this is just a temporary solution, so I will leave this thread open for anyone to put the proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is connected to the semver dependency. I think the command is not in your system path. I have the same dependency warning, but the command works. Have a look at the FAQ here: https://npmjs.org/package/phonegap

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have solved this by re-installing NodeJS. A restart also needed after installing phonegap to make the command line works.